# How can I give spaces while joining 2 strings together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I join 2 strings like:

```
print("not" + "X")
```

The result is like this:

```
notX
```

How could I make this into:

```
not X
```

Comment: A simple `print("not", "x")` will do as [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) can take multiple argumetns to print and has a `sep` argument to separate them which defaults to a space `" "`...

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
print("not","X")
# or:
' '.join(i for i in ['not','X'])
# or:
' '.join(('not','X'))
```

instead of:

```
print("not"+"X")
```

Comment: try now! edited a bit lol

Comment: Not the downvoter but `print("not", "X")` also works.

Comment: lol yes! i forgot about it